# How to disable wait cursor using MessageDlg

Tags: delphi

In Windows 10, when I execute

```
MessageDlg('Hello', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
```

I can notice the cursor switch to hour glass in a flash while.  I understand this is due the a flag `UseLatestCommonDialogs` to control the runtime using TTaskDialog.  Is that possible to disable the hour glass cursor flashing by not touching `UseLatestCommonDialogs`?

Comment: This is standard behaviour. You even see it with a simple `MessageBox`. I wouldn't care about it.

Comment: In some cases (heavy system load), it might take a second or two to display the message box. In these cases, the hourglass cursor is an important visual cue to the user.

Comment: Yes, in some cases only.  In most cases, the message box appear immediately, showing the hour glass cursor make the UI slower a bit.

Comment: Changing the cursor takes less than a millisecond. That's not noticeable. (The "flickering" is, however.)

Comment: In any case there's nothing to do, it's the system that sets the cursor. Otherwise you could simply set the VCL index of hourglass screen cursor to something else for the short duration that you call the box. It wouldn't be good anyway since you wouldn't be able to tell if it would take any amount of time to display the dialog beforehand however. And, IMHO, the argument that the setting of the cursor slows down the application is incredibly weak.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the [ShowCursor](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TScreen_Cursor.html)(False/True) function. This function is tied to Winapi.Windows and controls the cursor.

I assume you should walk through this example about hiding or changing the mouse cursor system-wide: https://flixengineering.com/archives/484

Comment: Trying to change the system-wide cursor is a bad idea. Please don't do that (*especially* not to "fix" a "problem" as minor as this.)